# OData .Net Core implementation adding filter append a parenthesis

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I am implementing the OData in my .NET Core project and I am trying to apply some filters.

When I use this filter

```
AddQueryOption("($filter",$"Userid eq '{id}'")
```

I am getting the query / URL as shown here:

```
https://xxx.yyy.be:8443/zzz/opu/odata/zzz/ABCDEFG/UserAPISet()?$filter=Userid eq '001'
```

I am looking for the query to be in the format

```
https://xxx.yyy.be:8443/zzz/opu/odata/zzz/ABCDEFG/UserAPISet?$filter=Userid eq '001'
```

I am not expecting a parenthesis `()` here `UserAPISet()`. What is the mistake I am making while adding a query?

Answer (score 0):

[This URL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4463e8f7-56c7-4d39-9d11-261f5d3c9ed5/dataservicecontext-createquery-method-issue-unwanted-parenthesis-in-operation-rest-url?forum=adodotnetdataservices) could be referred for answers related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding the open parenthesis, this is the code you should use:

```
.AddQueryOption("$filter",$"Userid eq '{id}'");
```

You had this:

```
.AddQueryOption("($filter",$"Userid eq '{id}'")
```